Space between subsection and subsubsection is too large
I have a section in my document like this

subsection{3.1.1 Distribution of Services by Attack Category}
\subsubsection{3.1.1.1 Insight}
In this analysis I want to find the type of attack that targets each service I used log in the 
count of packets to view all values.

\subsubsection{3.1.1.2 Spark code}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, frame=single, caption={\centering 3.1.1 Scripts}]
    service_attack_count = df.groupBy("service", "attack_cat") \
    .agg(count("*").alias("count")) \
    .orderBy(col("count").desc()).toPandas()
    pivot_df = service_attack_count.pivot_table(index='service', columns='attack_cat', values='count', fill_value=0)
    pivot_df = pivot_df.reset_index()
    plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
    plt.xscale('log')
    melted_df = pivot_df.melt(id_vars='service', var_name='attack_cat', value_name='count')
    sns.barplot(x='count', y='service', hue='attack_cat', data=melted_df, palette='bright')
    plt.title('Distribution of Services by Attack Category')
    plt.xlabel('Log Count')
    plt.ylabel('Service')
    plt.legend(title='Attack Category')
    plt.grid(True, linestyle='--', alpha=0.7)
    plt.show()
\end{lstlisting}


the out shape is

As you can see there are huge vertical spaces marked by the red lines how do I remove it?

Welcome to TeX.SX! With only a code snippet instead of a minimal working example I can only guess: Maybe you have one or more underfull \vbox messages in your log file? See also \flushbottom vs \raggedbottom (but IMHO there should be better duplicates, but currently I cannot find anyone).

We can't be sure without the code to reproduce this, but my guess is you have a large block at the top of the next page, so TeX is spacing this page out.  If that's the case, what do you want to happen?

Also related: Underfull vbox, geometry package

BTW: Instead of using lstlisting option frame, it could be better to use a tcolorbox with option breakable. See, e.g., chapter 17 and chapter 19 of the tcolorbox manual.
